# Android - HTTPUrlConnection POST data to server

Tags: android, database, post, get, httpurlconnection

I have a HTTPUrlConnection in my android app to post and get data from a webservice. At the moment I already achieved to get the data and display it, but now I need to post data to add it to my mysql database. How can this be achieved?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new HTTPAsyncTask().execute("http://192.168.0.16/MyDayFiles/borrar.php");
    }

    private class HTTPAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            try { // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
                return HttpGet(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }

        @Override // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //SHOW RESPONSE
        }
    }

    private String HttpGet(String myUrl) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";

        URL url = new URL(myUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // create HttpURLConnection
        conn.connect(); // make GET request to the given URL
        inputStream = conn.getInputStream(); // receive response as inputStream

        if(inputStream != null) { // convert inputstream to string
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        }else {
            result = "Hubo un error.";
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }
        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following method inside your `MainActivity` class:

```
public String HttpPost(String myUrl, String contentType, byte[] data) throws IOException
{ 
    URL url = new URL(myURL);
    HttpUrlConnection urlConnection = (HttpUrlConnection)url.openConnection();

    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

    //I suggest you to receive an ArrayList of Pair<String, String> or 
    //somethig and then iterate it setting all request header properties that 
    //you need.
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);

    OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(data);

    //You can handle HTTP errors based on this code
    int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode(); 
    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();

    if(inputStream == null) //If inputStream is null here, no error has occured. 
        inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    return convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: im sorry, the value I will send is in this line?     urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);

Comment: `contentType` is a variable that you will receive as a parameter in this method, like 'application/json'; 'text/html' etc.